# React Native Change Functional State inside State to Class State inside State

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

How to write this functional state to be class state?  I usually know how to change this in general, but what confuses me a lot here is because this third const state uses some other state inside itself, state const scrollAnim is used inside third state. So I dont understand how to write this for class component because this is written inside functional.

```
const [scrollAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
const [offsetAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  const [clampedScroll, setClampedScroll] = useState(Animated.diffClamp(
    Animated.add(
      scrollAnim.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 1],
        extrapolateLeft: 'clamp'
      }),
      offsetAnim
    ), 0, 1
  ));
```

What I tried:

```
state = {
    scrollAnim: (new Animated.Value(0)),
    offsetAnim: (new Animated.Value(0)),
    
    clampedScroll: (Animated.diffClamp(
      Animated.add(
        scrollAnim.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolateLeft: 'clamp'
        }),
        offsetAnim
      ), 0, 1
    ))
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple like this use `this.state` :

```
state = {
    scrollAnim: (new Animated.Value(0)),
    offsetAnim: (new Animated.Value(0)),
    
    clampedScroll: (Animated.diffClamp(
      Animated.add(
        this.state.scrollAnim.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolateLeft: 'clamp'
        }),
        this.state.offsetAnim
      ), 0, 1
    ))
  };
```

Comment: thank u it worked! also pls do u know whats the best way to use this ;  `const navbarTranslate = this.state.clampedScroll.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, HEADER_HEIGHT],
    outputRange: [0, -HEADER_HEIGHT],
    extrapolate: "clamp",
  });`  inside class component? whjat i need to change?

Comment: wat are the state variables here ? also  I suggest you learn about state in class component in general then you won't need help with this

Comment: literally just const varuiable im asking how to use it for class. so just focus on const part here pls

Comment: ahh yeah so you either decalre the const outside of the class ,or you decalre it as a class property like this ``` constructor(props){ this.navbarTranslate =...}```

Comment: about ur original code, i used it, and when i use it whereever i call these states they arent found i dont know why. it says this.state.scrollAnim is undefined `this.state.clampedScroll(
              Animated.diffClamp(
                Animated.add(
                  this.state.scrollAnim.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [0, 1],
                    extrapolateLeft: "clamp",
                  }),
                  this.state.offsetAnim
                ),
                0,
                height
              )
            );`

Comment: can you provide your state object

Comment: `state = {
   
    scrollAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
    offsetAnim: new Animated.Value(0),

    clampedScroll: Animated.diffClamp(
      Animated.add(
        this.state.scrollAnim.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolateLeft: "clamp",
        }),
        this.state.offsetAnim
      ),
      0,
      1
    ),
  };`

Comment: i mean its exactly what u wrote

Comment: is it because i try to use this.state inside a function? some guy wrote this answer somewhere else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359282/react-native-state-undefined but idk is it that??

Comment: this error is weird because i call many other states, i didnt show them inside my state object to u because they are irrelevant but i call all other members of state normally and with same way... idk why only this doesnt work?

Comment: i read somewhere "You need to bind the function to keyword this" maybe i need sht like that

Comment: yeah if you have any function that you're using inside component you should bind it , so that when you use ```this``` it refers to the component